# PROC UCM in SAS: How to specify day of week and month of the year seasonality in daily data series

Tags: sas, time-series, forecasting

I have daily data for 2 years starting from jan1 2014 till december 31 2015. I want to forecast for next 365 days using this data set.

*Code**

```
PROC UCM data=Mydata;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
id date interval=day; /*set the interval as day*/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
model Sold;
irregular;
level;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
slope ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
cycle period=365.24 rho=1 variance=0 noest=(rho period variance);                                                                                                                                                                                               
estimate;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
forecast lead=365 OUTFOR=Ucmm.DATA;                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
run;
```

There is a trend based on day of the week and month of the year. How do I specify that?

I understand for day of week it can be set as 7. For month how can I specify that? as some months have 31 days while some others have 30 and yet February has 28/29 days. How do I solve this? I know it can be specified using `season;` command. But how?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. For a quick solution, I would recommend manually creating dummy variables in the original dataset that you can specify as input variables. I am certain there are better and more advanced ways of using the `season` or `splineseason` statements to achieve better estimates, but I have not used this particular procedure much compared to the other ETS procs.

```
data want;
    set have;
    array month[*] Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov;
    do i = 1 to dim(month);
         month[i] = (month(date) = i);
    end;

    drop i;
run;


proc ucm data=want;
     model Sold = Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov;
       irregular;
       level;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
       slope ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
       cycle period=365.24 rho=1 variance=0 noest=(rho period variance);                                                                                                                                                                                               
       estimate;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
       forecast lead=365 OUTFOR=Ucmm.DATA;                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option to the month dummies: Proc UCM has a separate statement called BLOCKSEASON that sits over the SEASON statement. You could specify a season of 7 for day of the week, and then 365.24/12 as the block.